# Simple test for guard/listen listener

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, listener

I am using the guard/listen gem to write a listener for directory changes. When a file gets added to a directory, I create an empty `done.txt` file in that directory.

It works as I expect when manually testing but am not sure how to write a test for it as the listener needs to be running in its own process.

I tried using a fork but it kind of creates a closure I didn't expect.

Here's my listener:

```
require 'listen'

class Listener

  def initialize(directory)
    @directory = directory
  end

  def start
    listener = Listen.to(@directory, only: /\.txt$/) do |modified, added, removed|
      if added
        File.new('done.txt', 'w') if rp_checksum == my_checksum
      end
    end

    listener.start
    sleep
  end

end
```

And my test:

```
RSpec.describe Listener do

  it 'starts the listener' do
    fork do
      listener = Listener.new("#{Dir.getwd}")
      listener.start
    end

    expect(listener.processing?).to eq(true)
  end
```

And the error I get:

```
   NameError:
     undefined local variable or method `listener' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Listener:0x007fdc91980768>
   # ./listener_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Perhaps I can daemonize the listener but I'm not sure how to go about that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I don't really need to test that the listener works as it's probably well tested so I just extracted the `if file added` part to a separate method and tested that.

Yay for self-realization!